# Assembly generation failed - does not have a strong name

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im getting the following error in the `Portable Class Library (PCL)` in **Xamarin**, how to resolve this,?

Assembly generation failed -- `Referenced assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core' does not have a strong name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Xamarin.Forms` assemblies distributed through nuget.org are not strong-signed.

You're trying to strong-sign your application assembly, and this require all dependencies to be strong-signed too. That's the problem you're seeing.

IMHO, strong-signing application adds none to very little value in mobile, esp on Android and iOS.

Comment: i havent even changed anything. I dont even know how to do it but i am seeing same warnings. how am I doing it and how can I stop it?